# laravel iis web.config apply only to specific routes

Tags: iis

I have laravel running on an iis server. There is a default rewrite rule that redirects all unknown urls to index.php

I would like to apply this rule only to urls with a path starting with `/api`
and additionally to the exact path `/login`

So

`mydomain1.com/assets/logo.png` should point to the file or fail if it does not exist

```
mydomain1.com/api/users
mydomain2.com/api/posts/tags
mydomain1.com/login
```

should all redirect to index.php

This is the rule without the conditions:

```
        <rule name="Laravel5" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false"/>
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
```